# how to embed pdf file in html with security?

Tags: html, security, pdf

I am using below code to display pdf file in HTML

```
<object data="data/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
<a href="data/file.pdf">test.pdf</a>
</object>
```

But In above code we have to specify path name and folder name so it is not so secure. Crawler can find this path, so using some algorithms(robot) it is very easy to download other file those are stored in that folder. 
How to secure this, is there any option to prevent this from robots?.

Comment: Probably if you want to keep it something _secure_ then you shouldn't publish it on Internet. To be serious: to prevent robots to read something you have few options (AFAIK): authentication and/or (re)CAPTCHA. JavaScript is/was also an option but a robot may handle that too (at very basic level you may simply build href when user press a button or when mouse hover your link).

Comment: thanks @Kent. But my concept is, I don't want to show path in mouse hover of that link or in page source.

Comment: at the end the main thing is to secure files so I will definitely try locking directory technique. thanks @Kent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do the following:

- Password protect the page (with the server-side code).
- Generate unique links like (*/getpdf/some_random_string_or_md5_hash_of_random_string.pdf*) for every PDF file (using server-side code) that will a) check for the current time and the validity of the random name generated (if it has expired or not) then b) will redirect to the source files (not really hiding the source because of the redirection) to be displayed or stream the PDF file content (this is more secure though could seriously add the load to the server).
- Finally add [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org) to the folder and hope that crawlers will follow restrictions it sets.

Answer (score 0):

If the other files in the directory are not to be downloaded, ever, they shouldn't be in a directory that is available to the http server. You can use directory permissions in your http server (eg., config directives and .htaccess in Apache) to control access to directories. Only configure access for directories you need to expose to the web, and only store files in them that you want the web to access.

If you want to avoid including a path in the HTML, you will need to write some dynamic code (eg, php, asp, or any number of server-side options). Your code on the server would need to handle the request for the file and return the file's content manually.